# Linux - Find out the current working directory of a process?

Tags: bash, process

If i have a process PID X, how can I find out what directory it was running in? I can see with `ps aux | grep X` the full command line that it was invoked with. However in this case it's `./script.sh`, and I want to see which `script.sh` it's running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with `/proc/PID/exe` is that, for shell scripts, it shows the location of the shell. The problem with `/proc/PID/cwd` is that is shows the *current* working directory of the process. If the process changes directories, that is reflected in the target of that symlink.

This will show what the $PWD was at the time the script was started (substitute the process ID you're interested in where you see "PID"):

```
procdir=$(grep -az "\bPWD" /proc/PID/environ); echo $procdir
```

or simply:

```
grep -az "\bPWD" /proc/PID/environ
```

This will show the command that started it so you can see if a relative or absolute directory was used:

```
proccmd=$(grep -az PROC_NAME /proc/PID/cmdline); echo $proccmd
```

or simply:

```
grep -az PROC_NAME /proc/PID/cmdline
```

Together, these should show you which script is being run. For one started with `./` all you need is `procdir`.

Comment: pwdx is better than this.

Answer (score 8):

There's a simpler answer, and that's to use `pwdx`, as detailed [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-report-current-working-directory-of-process.html)

Comment: This is the better answer.